# Juniper EX uplink module for access downlinks

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

We have a Juniper EX-4200 (1Gbps downlinks) with the SFP+ uplink module. The switch is connected to our providers via 10x aggregated 1Gbps ports (ge-0/0/0 to ge-0/0/9). Can we connect a server to the 10Gbps uplink module (xe-0/1/0) and expect to be able to push 10 Gbps from the server in multiple or a single TCP connection? I know the uplink module cancels 2 ports in EX-3200, but does it cancel ports in EX-4200 switches? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect server to 10 gbps uplink and you push data from your server to the aggregated uplinks you will have 1 gbps speed for single flow, speed will not be aggregated for any single TCP flow but it will use single uplink.
For the uplink module it can be configured to support up to four 1-gigabit SFP transceivers or up to two 10-gigabit small form-factor pluggable (SFP+) transceivers.

Answer (score 1):

Mr.lock is correct - I would only add that no - enabling uplink ports on the EX4200 does not disable the last 4 fixed ports as it does on the EX3200.